# Disable bluetooth keyboard for second mac

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I've searched through some sites and couldn't find any solution for my problem, so finally landed here :)

I have two mac's in my job - one has bluetooth keyboard, one wired. I want to permanently disable bluetooth keyboard for that with wired keyboard. Now it automatically pairs with Mac which is first turned on. How I can do that?

Thanks!

Comment: The amplest way is turn bluetooth off on the wired Mac if you can do without it

Answer (score 2):

On the second Mac, under **System Preferences > Bluetooth > "Paired Devices" >** right click (or <kbd>control</kbd> + click) the device (keyboard) > Remove. You must be connected to bluetooth to remove the device.

Under "Advanced" uncheck "Open Bluetooth Setup Assistant at Startup if No Keyboard is Connected"

Subsequently, you can disable Bluetooth altogether in the same pane > "Turn Bluetooth Off."